# Android Why my FTP file transfer succeed when in USB debug mode with Eclipse and fail when standalone wifi?

Tags: android, eclipse, ftp, usb

I'm developing an application, and I need transfer files from/to FTP server using wifi.
When debugging, connect with USB cable to Eclipse, the application works... but, when I in standalone mode, not using Eclipse IDE, the transfer not happens.
The FTP server is local, and I can watch the connection being made... and stuck in file transfer

```
    (000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (Tim.Kosse@gmx.de)
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> 220 Please visit http://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> PASV
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> 530 Please log in with USER and PASS first.
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> USER th38939
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> 331 Password required for th38939
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - (not logged in) (192.168.1.113)> PASS ***********
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 230 Logged on
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> TYPE I
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 200 Type set to I
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> CWD /public_ftp/cobradores/cobrador_01/remessa/
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 250 CWD successful. "/public_ftp/cobradores/cobrador_01/remessa" is current directory.
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> PWD
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 257 "/public_ftp/cobradores/cobrador_01/remessa" is current directory.
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> PORT 192,168,1,113,202,216
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 200 Port command successful
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> NLST
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 150 Opening data channel for directory list.
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 226 Transfer OK
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> PORT 192,168,1,113,133,181
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:20 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 200 Port command successful
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:21 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> RETR ARQUIVO_TESTE.REM
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:21 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 150 Opening data channel for file transfer.
(000056)15/01/2013 16:42:21 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 226 Transfer OK
(000056)15/01/2013 16:44:21 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> 421 Connection timed out.
(000056)15/01/2013 16:44:21 - th38939 (192.168.1.113)> disconnected.
```

Any clue ?

Comment: probably firewalling v.s. active/passive ftp.

Comment: the server has permission to firewall and I start in passive mode just after connecting to server... this conditions are the same when I'm debugging with Eclipse/USB and standalone, at first works, the later not...

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the CPU is going to sleep (it won't go to sleep if the debugger is connected). But you also need to keep wifi connection alive as well.

You need various locks to keep the device active. A WifiLock at least. And a WakeLock with CPU lock as well. The WakeLock should be acquired via PowerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"tag"). PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK is the only lock that prevents the CPU from going into sleep mode.

If the process is going to run for any length of time, you will also need to run in a service that has called Service.startForeground. Android will terminate any service or background app every 30 minutes (and sometimes much more often than that) if you haven't called startForeground. Beware of bugs in Context.bindService. Do not use the Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT flag when binding to the service, as this will trigger bugs in Android 4.x that prevent the service from being assigned foreground status.

Another interesting bug that can come into play. Some Android devices implement low-power  modes incorrectly. When running in power-saving mode, the system uptime clock runs at a fraction of the speed it should. If you are using sleep or other mechanism for delay, they can take much much longer than they should.

Comment: The sleep might indeed be an issue: key question to the OP would be if the screen remains on during the attempt (while the processor can run with the screen off, it doesn't sleep with it on and responsive)

Comment: The application is already using wake lock, the code is straight forward in a function, when things are certain the process is quite fast, the files are very small...